# How can I show content on hover by ID?

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I need show the content ohover of different product list with their own id.

This is my code..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gift").hide();
  $(".box").hover(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $(".gift").show();
  }, function() {
    $(".gift").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.gift {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="producto_1" class="box">
  <div class="gift">
    PRODUCTO 1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="producto_2" class="box">
  <div class="gift">
    PRODUCTO 2
  </div>
</div>
<div id="producto_3" class="box">
  <div class="gift">
    PRODUCTO 3
  </div>
</div>
```

and a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jdiazs/2sdhup15/)

I can get the id when hover on each box and save it into `var = id`, but im not sure how make the show function with that id.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2sdhup15/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JS for this at all, use CSS's `:hover` selector, like this:

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.gift {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.box:hover .gift {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="gift">
    PRODUCTO 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="gift">
    PRODUCTO 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="gift">
    PRODUCTO 3
  </div>
</div>
```

If you really did want to do this in JS, which I would advise against, you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the `hover` event, then `toggle()` its child `.gift` element. Whichever way you achieve this the `id` attributes are irrelevant, which is a good thing as it keeps the logic DRY.

```js
$('.box').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.gift').toggle();
});
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.gift {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="gift">
    PRODUCTO 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="gift">
    PRODUCTO 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="gift">
    PRODUCTO 3
  </div>
</div>
```